How to write an extendable Kubernetes operator
My company have won an open source project that involves creation of a Kubernetes operator to manage user workspaces for a web platform. We have an existing operator for another project that does the job, but it contains some project IP. I have been tasked to refactor out the generic functionality into a core package, and structure the module so that it is extendable. We are using Kubebuilder framework to create the operator. It's also worth mentioning that, although I am an experienced software engineer, I am new to Go.
I have scaffolded the core project using Kubebuilder. I added the workspace API and everything works as expected. The functionality just now is minimal, when a workspace resource is created the API will create a namespace with the same name as the workspace resource. Key excerpts below:
# steps to scaffold project
kubebuilder init --domain my.domain --owner "My Org"
kubebuilder create api --group core --kind Workspace --version v1alpha1

// (core) api/v1alpha1/workspace_types.go
...
type WorkspaceSpec struct {}  // no functionality required yet

type WorkspaceStatus struct {
    // The name of the namespace for the workspace
    Namespace string `json:"namespace,omitempty"`
} // added namespace field to status

type Workspace struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`

    Spec   WorkspaceSpec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status WorkspaceStatus `json:"status,omitempty"`
} // boilerplate, unchanged from scaffolding

type WorkspaceList struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ListMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    Items           []Workspace `json:"items"`
} // boilerplate, unchanged from scaffolding

// (core) controller/workspace_controller.go
import (
    corev1alpha1 "github.com/UKEODHP/workspace-controller/api/v1alpha1"
)
...
type WorkspaceReconciler struct {
    client.Client
    Scheme *runtime.Scheme
}

func (r *WorkspaceReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    // Get a reference to the workspace that has been updated
    workspace := &corev1alpha1.Workspace{}
    if err := r.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, workspace); err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, client.IgnoreNotFound(err)
    }

    // my reconciliation logic

    return ctrl.Result{}, nil
}

Note that I removed the workspace_controller module from the internal directory created during the scaffolding as I want to make it importable in isolation by the extending project.
Now, my design is to allow a user to scaffold their own Kubebuilder project and reuse and extend the functionality provided by the core module.
Project is scaffolded similarly to above, but with different domain and group. I embedded the structs that define the API in the newly scaffolded API.
// (extension) api/v1alpha1/workspace_types.go
...
import (
    ...
    corev1alpha1 "github.com/MyOrg/workspace-controller/api/v1alpha1"
)
...
type WorkspaceSpec struct {
    corev1alpha1.WorkspaceSpec `json:",inline"`
} // embedded core spec

type WorkspaceStatus struct {
    corev1alpha1.WorkspaceStatus `json:",inline"`
} // embedded core status

type Workspace struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`

    Spec   WorkspaceSpec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status WorkspaceStatus `json:"status,omitempty"`
} // unmodified, so there is no link between core Workspace struct and ext Workspace struct

type WorkspaceList struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ListMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    Items           []Workspace `json:"items"`
} // unmodified

So far so good, I can generate the CRDs with make manifests and the code runs. The issue I have is reusing the reconciliation logic in the core. In the controller/workspace_controller.go above, the type in the Reconcile method is hardcoded, and will differ from the extension type. When I try and call the core Reconcile from the extension Reconcile then it does not find any resources, which I understand since I hardcoded the core Workspace struct type.
// (extension) controller/workspace_controller.go
import (
    ...
    extv1alpha1 "extension/api/v1alpha1"
    corecontroller "github.com/MyOrg/workspace-controller/controller"
)
...
type WorkspaceReconciler struct {
    corecontroller.WorkspaceReconciler
}

func (r *WorkspaceReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    // Get a reference to the workspace that has been updated
    workspace := &extv1alpha1.Workspace{}
    if err := r.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, workspace); err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, client.IgnoreNotFound(err)
    }  // this call finds the extension resource

    // call embedded core Reconciler
    r.WorkspaceReconciler.Reconcile(ctx, req)  // becomes a no-op because workspace resource not found, which is understandable

    return ctrl.Result{}, nil
}

So, my question is, how do other extendable Kubebuilder APIs deal with this issue? Is there something I have missed? Or can I use any features of Go that I haven't thought of, such as reflection, to infer the type of resource I am looking for from the Reconciler or any other available variables so that when using the core module I get core.Workspace and when using the extension module I get extension.Workspace?
Is anyone aware of any extendable Kubebuilder API open source projects that I can reference to see how they do it?

What do you mean by "extendable API"?  Kubebuilder generates a huge amount of stuff for you "under the hood"; if the final project needs to define its own spec and status fields and its own reconcile function, your framework layer doesn't seem to be providing much beyond what Kubebuilder has already.

The rest of the functionality planned for the core package is along the lines of providing a namespace for each user workspace, providing them with block AWS storage, S3 storage. The extension API is to do with AI models etc that is very specific to an existing project. We want to provide the core API as a reusable API and allow other projects to reuse the "core functionality" as they wish. I imagine people wanting to add additional fields to the Spec and Status but for the core functionality to operate regardless.

Since i didn't find an answer here I'll share the solution I came up with. I defined a Reconciler interface that takes the *WorkspaceSpec and *WorkspaceStatus structs that I defined as inputs and make the updates required. I then loop over these reconcilers in the main reconciler and apply the updated statuses to the Workspace resource for each. Any user who wanted to add functionality can still embed my Spec and Status, and pass them only to the reconcilers as they see fit in their reconciler logic. All interaction with the user's custom resource is at the top level.
